# Uniqueness of universal covering without local path-connectedness

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $B$ be a topological space. A *universal covering* of $B$ is defined to be a simply connected covering space. Suppose $B$ has a universal covering. Is such a covering unique (up to a homeomorphism)?

When $B$ is locally path-connected, the lifting criterion easily implies the uniqueness of a universal covering. This can also be shown 'by hand' using the homotopy lifting property, or can be shown by playing with the fibered product of two universal coverings. But now $B$ is not assumed to be locally path-connected, and none of these work.

**Question:** Is the universal covering unique?

Comment: You don't need $B$ to be locally path connected. Universal coverings are homeomorphic by the universal property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Universal_covers

Comment: @freakish Do you have a proof for the universal property?